# Run Watir on a client browser

Tags: ruby, browser, watir

I wish to develop a browser extension that receives voice command input and simulates users' actions such as link clicking/following, button pushing, etc. I found that Watir might be useful for this task, but is it possible to run Watir on a client browser?

In my understanding, we cannot execute Ruby on a client directly, right?
Is there any Watir clone for Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir requires that both it and Ruby be installed on the client machine. This cannot be done through a browser extension.

Comment: Is it impossible even if I use NPAPI? I just need confirmation. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, what prevents a browser extension from bundling Ruby and Watir?

Comment: Reading about NPAPI says that it allows you to include javascript and html. Watir and Ruby include a lot more than this. Like Ruby and Executables.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, Watir is able to handle your needs. Watir supports all leading browsers like IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

When you run a Watir script, it opens according browser window and follows instruction like clicking on a link, filling a text field and then submit etc automatically. Have a look at the examples [here](http://watir.com/examples/).

So I believe this will satisfy your first worry/question. And if this is the case, do you need any Watir clone in JS? I guess no :)

Comment: Your examples seem to work when we run the script in the command line, but my question is how to do that via a browser extension. Perhaps, it is because of my confusing explanation. Let my try again. Suppose I manage to create a browser extension that understands voice commands like 'click a button'. I want Watir to do just that in a user's browser via my extension.